# How to loop on the Cartesian product space of sets in R?

Tags: r, iterator, cartesian-product

How to loop on the Cartesian product space of sets in R? Let's say I have some vectors and I want to iterate on their Cartesian product space.

```
is_igg <- c(TRUE,FALSE)
p_val_thres <- c(5e-5,5e-8)
ld_thres <- c(0.5,0.8)
```

It would be tedious to write three for loop nested at each level:

```
for (x in is_igg) {
  for (y in is_igg) {
    for (z in ld_thres) {
      do something with (x,y,z)
    }
  }
}
```

Is there an alternative that is cleaner than this to achieve such purpose? In Python this is quite easy because one can just `zip(...)` and that creates an iterator. But I don't know how to do this in R.

Comment: If it is not so big vector, you can use `expand.grid(is_igg, p_val_thres, ld_thres)`

Answer (score 0):

We may do this with `expand.grid` to create all the combinations and then may do with `apply` by looping over the rows (`MARGIN = 1`)

```
apply(expand.grid(is_igg, p_val_thres, ld_thres), 1, FUN = yourfn)
```